# copy images from one S3 bucket to diff account s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using RESTful API, API provider having images on S3 bucket more than 80GB size.
I need to download these images and upload in my AWS S3 bucket, its time taking job.

Is there any way to copy image from API to my S3 bucket instead of I download and upload again.

I talked with API support they saying you are getting image URL, so its up to you how you handle,

I am using laravel.

**is it way to get the sourced images url's and directly move images to S3 instead of first I download and upload.**

Thanks

Comment: Do you have AWS credentials that allow access to the objects in Amazon S3, or do you merely have an anonymous URL (with no authentication) that is used to access the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think downloading and re-uploading to different accounts would be inefficient plus pricey for the API Provider. Instead of that I would talk to the respective API Provider and try to replicate the images across accounts.

Post replicate you can [Amazon S3 inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) for various information related to the objects in the bucket.

[Configuring replication when the source and destination buckets are owned by different accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-walkthrough-2.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You want "S3 Batch Operations". Search for "xcopy".

You do not say how many images you have, but 1000 at 80GB is 80TB, and for that size you would not even want to be downloading to a temporary EC2 instance in the same region file by file which might be a one or two day option otherwise, you will still pay for ingress/egress.

I am sure AWS will do this in an ad-hoc manner for a price, as they would do if you were migrating from the platform.

It may also be easier to allow access to the original bucket from the alternative account, but this is no the question.